# Bootstrap 3.0 Modal Breaking Width Layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a simple Modal in bootstrap, nothing modified, simply:

`$('#myModal').modal({backdrop:false})`

But when the modal opens it's wider than the browser, not matter what size the window is and creates a 20px or so space.

[image]

Any ideas why this is happening, my layout is based off of the Jumbotron template, nothing unique, just color changes mostly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer for anyone else that's having this issue.

```
body.modal-open,
.modal-open .navbar-fixed-top,
.modal-open .navbar-fixed-bottom {
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

in bootstrap.css

In your theme stylesheet set:

```
body.modal {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Thanks for looking.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21604674/bootstrap-modal-background-jumps-to-top-on-toggle)