# Buttons on Page Stop Working After Twitter Bootstrap Modal Dismissed in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am using Twitter Bootstrap's (v3.1) modal dialog and when I show a dialog and dismiss it, any buttons that were not on the screen when the modal displayed are no longer clickable in IE 11.
[image]
As shown in the above illustration, the I have multiple buttons to show modals and they are further down the page  than where the modal displays (at the top of the page).  The first modal displays properly.  However, once I dismiss that modal and scroll back down the page to click on another button, the buttons are no longer clickable.
My button code:

```
<button type="button" id="btnPreviewSales" name="btnPreviewSales" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#previewSalesModal"><span id="btnSalesPrevImg" class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> Preview Sales</button>
```

My modal code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="previewSalesModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="previewSalesModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="previewSalesModalLabel">Preview Sales</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <img src="preview.jpg" alt="Sales Preview" class="img-responsive" />
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It works fine in other browsers (Chrome, Firefox) and I have the X-UA compatible tags properly set.  What can I do to get the buttons clickable again after dismissing the modal in IE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution.  I also noticed that the modal was jumping to the top of the page each time and went looking for a solution to that problem.  I found [Bootstrap modal: background jumps to top on toggle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21604674/bootstrap-modal-background-jumps-to-top-on-toggle) and the recommended the solution was to override a bootstrap style:

```
body.modal-open {
    overflow: visible;
}
```