# Bootstrap modal scrolls background content

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

When I open a modal, the background page is automatically scrolled to the top.  In my css if I remove `html{ overflow-y: scroll };`  I fix this behavior but now the scrollbar to the right disappears and my navbar shifts to the right the same amount of space the scrollbar was taking up.

I want to be able to keep my overflow setting and have it so the background content doesn't scroll up.

**example_controller.rb**

```
def onsale
    @item= Products.first
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

**_header.html.erb**

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
            <li><%= link_to "Sale Items", onsale_path,  :remote => true %></li>
          </ul>
        <% end %>
</div>
```

**application.html.erb**
I put this in the body
 `<div id="sale-modal"></div>`

**onsale.js.erb**

```
$("#onsale-modal").html('<%= escape_javascript(render 'onsale') %>');
```

**_onsale.html.erb**

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <%= image_tag @item.picture.large.url %>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>$('#myModal').modal('show')</script>
```

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require bootstrap-select.min
//= require turbolinks
//= require fancybox
//= require_tree .

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
  $('.fancybox').fancybox({
    openEffect: 'elastic',
    closeEffect: 'elastic',
    prevEffect: 'fade',
    nextEffect: 'fade',
    padding: 10
  });

  if ($('#infinite-scrolling').length) {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var url = $('.pagination .next_page').attr('href');
      if (url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 60) {
        // TODO - Removing this line was causing duplicates to load so it's worth investigating the cause
        $('.pagination').html('Please Wait...');
        return $.getScript(url);
      }
    });
    return $(window).scroll();
  }
  $('#myModal').modal('show')
  //Hide Scroll when modal about to show
    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
        $('html').css({
            'overflow': 'hidden'
        });
    });
    //add Scroll back when modal is hidden
    $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $('html').css({
            'overflow-y': 'scroll'
        });
    });
```

});

If I remove the script `<script>$('#myModal').modal('show')</script>` from the partial and put it in application.js, like it is above, the modal doesn't show up at all.  If I add the line `$('#myModal').modal('show')` to onsale.js.erb, the modal will show up fine.

Comment: I am opening with a tagging path link to an action in a controller.  Then using ajax to fetch a partial and put it in a div.

Comment: They talk about the issue here https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/5336.  Looks like the problem just went away for some people but I don't see a fix.

Comment: Let me know if there is other code you need to see.

Comment: sure, what solution is that?

Comment: The first solution for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21604674/bootstrap-modal-background-jumps-to-top-on-toggle worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21604674/bootstrap-modal-background-jumps-to-top-on-toggle) question worked for me. I just added

```
body.modal-open {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

to my css.